# Wrap socket.io emit and on methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to create a custom version, that fits for my needs, of emit() and on() methods of socket.io.
I was able to do it for the emit() method like this:

```
socket._emit = function () {
        console.log('socket._emit ', arguments);
        event = arguments[0];
        data ={
            'username': user.username,
            'token': user.token,
            'data': arguments[1]
        };
        socket.emit.apply(this, [event, JSON.stringify(data)]);
};
```

I have problems to do that for the on() method, because I'm not able to get the data of the callback function, so now my custom _on() does not do anything special, just calls the default on().

```
socket._on = function () {
        socket.on.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

My goal is to log every data received by the callback of the on() method. I tried something like this but didn't work.

```
socket._on = function () {
        callback = function(){
            console.log('socket._on ', //arguments from arguments[1]()//);
            arguments[1]();
        }
        socket.on.apply(this, [arguments[0], callback()]);
};
```

Any idea on how to improve my test?

Thanks, Alessandro

Comment: Have you worked this out yet?

Comment: Yes I was able to get some data from the callback. I posted an answer with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this solution:

```
var _onevent = socket.onevent;
socket.onevent = function (packet) {
    console.log('[S] On: ', packet);
    _onevent.call(socket, packet);
};
```

You need to investigate a bit the `packet` object in order to see what matters to you.

Worked for socket.io 1.7.2.